# Java - error after initialising game - minesweeper

Tags: java, oop, right-click, minesweeper

I am having this weird problem but I can't seem to figure it out. 
I have a button that says "new game". After I play the game once, and then press "new game" which goes back into to initGame(), I face a problem as I cannot right-click on cells that was the previous game's mines. I can left-click with no problem hence I am lost.

(p.s. if you want to advice me on how to shorten/simplify my code, feel free to do so too!)

Please advice, this is part of my code(everything else works fine):

```
private void initGame() {
    minesFlagged=10;
    tfFlag.setText(minesFlagged + "");
    CellMouseListener listener = new CellMouseListener();
   // Reset cells, mines, and flags
   for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
         // Set all cells to un-revealed
         btnCells[row][col].setEnabled(true);  // enable button
         btnCells[row][col].setForeground(FGCOLOR_NOT_REVEALED);
         btnCells[row][col].setBackground(BGCOLOR_NOT_REVEALED);
         btnCells[row][col].setFont(FONT_NUMBERS);
         btnCells[row][col].setText("");       // display blank
         mines[row][col] = false;   // clear all the mines
         flags[row][col] = false;   // clear all the flags
         zeroesVisit[row][col] = false;
         btnCells[row][col].setIcon(null);  
         btnCells[row][col].addMouseListener(listener); 
      }
   }

   for (int row = 0; row <= ROWS; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= COLS; col++) {
         sol[row][col]=-1;             
       }
    }

// Set the number of mines and the mines' location
   numMines = 10; //rmb the array starts from zero and ends at index 9
   for(int i=0;i<numMines;i++){
       Random rand = new Random();
       //get random position for next mine
       int row = rand.nextInt(ROWS);
       int col = rand.nextInt(COLS);
       while(mines[row][col]||mines[0][0]){//if this position is a mine
           //we get new position
           row = rand.nextInt(ROWS);
           col = rand.nextInt(COLS);       
       }
       mines[row][col]=true;
   }
}
private void findSol(int rowSelected,int colSelected){
    for (int rr = rowSelected - 1; rr<= rowSelected + 1; rr++){//finding how many surrounding mines
        for (int cc = colSelected - 1; cc <= colSelected + 1; cc++){
            if(rr>=0 && cc>=0 && rr<ROWS && cc<COLS){
               if (mines[rr][cc]){
                   sol[rowSelected][colSelected]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    private class CellMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      // Determine the (row, col) of the JButton that triggered the event
      int rowSelected = -1,colSelected = -1;

      // Get the source object that fired the Event
      JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
      // Scan all rows and columns, and match with the source object
      boolean found = false;
      boolean done = true;
      for (int row = 0; row < ROWS && !found; ++row) {
         for (int col = 0; col < COLS && !found; ++col) {
            if (source == btnCells[row][col]) {
               rowSelected = row;
               colSelected = col;
               found = true;   // break both inner/outer loops
            }
         }
      }

      // Left-click to reveal a cell; Right-click to plant/remove the flag.
      if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && (!flags[rowSelected][colSelected])) {  // Left-button clicked
         //If you hit a mine, game over - OKAY
         //Otherwise, reveal the cell and display the number of surrounding mines - okay
          if (mines[rowSelected][colSelected]){
             btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(BGCOLOR_REVEALED);
             imgMines = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Bombicon.png"));                
             btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setIcon(imgMines);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over! Try to complete the game~");
         }else{
             btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(FGCOLOR_REVEALED); //though foreground is text color  
             btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setIcon(null);
             sol[rowSelected][colSelected]=0;
             findSol(rowSelected,colSelected);

             if(sol[rowSelected][colSelected]>0){
                 btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setText(""+sol[rowSelected][colSelected]); 
                 btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].removeMouseListener(this);
                 colorCell(rowSelected,colSelected);                     
             }               
             else if(sol[rowSelected][colSelected]==0){                                                              
                 do{
                     done = true;
                     for(int r=0;r<ROWS;r++){//scanning through whole board
                         for(int c=0;c<COLS;c++){                               
                             if(sol[r][c]==0 && !zeroesVisit[r][c]){
                                 zeroesVisit[r][c]=true;
                                 for(int row=r-1;row<=r+1;row++){//open the 8 surrounding cells
                                     for(int col=c-1;col<=c+1;col++){
                                         if(row>=0 && col>=0 && row<ROWS && col<COLS){//make sure not out of bounds
                                             btnCells[row][col].setBackground(FGCOLOR_REVEALED);
                                             btnCells[row][col].setIcon(null);
                                             sol[row][col]=0;
                                             findSol(row,col);             
                                             btnCells[row][col].removeMouseListener(this);  
                                             if(sol[row][col]>0){
                                                 btnCells[row][col].setText(""+sol[row][col]);                                                                                                      
                                                 colorCell(row,col);                                                     
                                             }
                                             else if(sol[row][col]==0){
                                                 btnCells[row][col].setText("");
                                                 done=false;//to prompt looping again
                                             }
                                         }                                   
                                     }                                                               
                                 }
                             }                                                                                                  
                         }       
                     }
                 }while(!done);//scan again to find all/any the zero cells                                                                                          
             }
         }

      }else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) { // right-button clicked
         //If the location is flagged, remove the flag
         // Otherwise, plant a flag. - COMPLETED
          if(flags[rowSelected][colSelected]){
              flags[rowSelected][colSelected]=false;
              btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(BGCOLOR_NOT_REVEALED);
              btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setIcon(null);
              minesFlagged++;
              tfFlag.setText(minesFlagged + "");
          }else{
              flags[rowSelected][colSelected]=true;
              btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(FGCOLOR_NOT_REVEALED);
              imgFlags = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("whiteflag.png"));
              btnCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setIcon(imgFlags);  
              minesFlagged--;
              tfFlag.setText(minesFlagged + "");
          }
      }

      //Check if the player has won, after revealing this cell - COMPLETED
      int completeCount=0,flagCount=0;
      for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
          for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
              if(!mines[row][col] && btnCells[row][col].getBackground()==FGCOLOR_REVEALED){                   
                  completeCount++;
                  if((ROWS*COLS-numMines) == completeCount){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CONGRATULATIONS!");
                  }                  
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: is mouseClicked called when you right click the cell? (did you put a breakpoint there?) nevertheless, you are mixing UI and logic in your code - this is a very bad software architecture practice - i'd suggest to learn about separating UI and logic.
one more thing, maybe unrelated - did you remove all mouse listeners after the game ended?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are calling addMouseListener each time the game is initialized.  This does not replace the existing MouseListener from previous games, so you now have an additional listener on buttons where you did not call removeMouseListener.  I would investigate this first, if certain buttons are not firing the event.

It would be better to only add the listeners once, when the Frame is first created.  Then add logic to the mouseClicked event method to ignore clicks on buttons which are "deactivated", rather than removing and adding the listener over and over again.

If you must take this approach, I recommend removing all MouseListeners from any buttons which have them (they can be found using the method getMouseListeners), before adding the listener inside the initGame method.

As stated by ArielB, it is best practice to separate your model (the position of the mines and states of the tiles, etc) into another class away from your UI code.